# bash - commands in variables with pipes

Tags: bash, pipe, command-substitution

Can someone explain why `A` and `B` behave differently?

```
A=`echo hello how are you | wc -w`
```

and

```
CMD="echo hello how are you | wc -w"
B=`$CMD`
```

They give different results:

```
$echo $A
4

$echo $B
hello how are you | wc -w
```

What I would like to have is a command in a variable that I can execute at several points of a script and get different values to compare. It used to work fine but if the command has a pipe, it doesn't work.

Comment: Storing shell syntax (like pipes, quotes, etc) in variables doesn't work. Variables are for data, not executable code. If you want to store executable code, use a function, that's what they're for. See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) and many previous questions about this (but avoid all suggestions involving `eval` -- it is a huge bug magnet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ``` `` ``` (i.e. backticks) or  `$()` in bash referred as **command substitution**.
- `""` - used e.g. to preserves the literal value of characters, i.e. data.

1. In the your first example, the command `echo hello how are you | wc -w` is executed and its value `4` assigned to `A`, hence you get `4`.
2. In your second example it an assignment of a string to a variable `B` and by `` `$CMD` `` the `|` is not "evaluated" **because of late word splitting** (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388352/393118) for further information), and you get `hello how are you | wc -w`.

What you need can be done with `eval` command as follows:

```bash
CMD="echo hello how are you | wc -w"
echo `eval $CMD`            # or just eval "$CMD"
# Output is 4
```

Comment: _an assignment of a string to a variable B and by `$CMD` its value is not "evaluated"_ --> if that were the case, then `B` would equal "echo hello how are you | wc -w" but it doesn't: it equals "hello how are you | wc -w". So the `echo` command _was_ executed. It just didn't pipe into `wc`.

Comment: @k314159 adjusted my answer.

Comment: I still don't understand what is the logic behind running the echo but not the pipe... But thanks for giving the eval solution!

Comment: @MartinMassera Because of 'late word splitting' the pipe it not evaluated,  see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388352/393118 for further information. I add the link to my answer as well.

Comment: It's important to use quotes -- `eval "$CMD"`, not `eval $CMD`. Otherwise you can get filenames injected into code if your string word-splits to include any globs.